# Filter duplicate values from array using javascript/typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, angular7

I have an array of Days as follows:
[monday 3sep,tuesday 4sep, monday 10sep]

I want to get only unique days of the week in my filtered array that should be:
[monday 3sep,tuesday 4sep]

how can i filter this array using ES6 map() and filter()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your array is an array of strings

```
var arry = ['monday 3sep','tuesday 4sep', 'monday 10sep']
```

if so you can solve this by using a second array

```
var secondarray = []
var filtered = arry.filter(i=>{
  var split = i.split(' ');
  if(secondarray.indexOf(split[0])==-1){
     secondarray.push(split[0]);
     return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```